# recyclerview item mishap(undesirable behaviour) in android studio

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recycler view with a list of items and each of those items have checkboxes attached to them. When a checkbox is checked, it behaves properly and there is no problem with unwanted items getting checked. But when a checked item is deleted, then the unwanted item gets checked.

My Adapter Class :

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskHolder> {
private static List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
private static OnItemClickListener listener;
private static TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter();


@NonNull

@Override
public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.task_item, parent, false);
    return new TaskHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TaskHolder holder, int position) {
    Task currentTask = tasks.get(position);
    holder.a_tname.setText(currentTask.getTname());
    holder.a_tdate.setText(currentTask.getTDate());
    holder.a_ttime.setText(currentTask.getTTime());
    holder.a_tprior.setText(currentTask.getTprior());
    holder.bind(tasks.get(position));
   holder.bind2(tasks.get(position));

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasks.size();
}
public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
    Collections.sort( tasks, Task.comparepriority);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public Task getTaskAt(int position){
    return tasks.get(position);
}

 class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    private final TextView a_tname;
    private final TextView a_tdate;
    private  final TextView a_ttime;
    private final TextView a_tprior;
    ImageView priorityIndicator;
    CheckBox checkbox;


    public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        a_tname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_tname);
        a_tdate=itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_tdate);
        a_ttime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_ttime);
        a_tprior = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_tprior);
        priorityIndicator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priorityIndicator);
        checkbox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);




        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(listener!=null&&position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    listener.onItemClick(tasks.get(position));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void bind(Task task){
        int drawableId;int red = R.color.red;int yellow = R.color.yellow;int green = R.color.green;
        int color1 = ContextCompat.getColor(a_tprior.getContext(), red);
        int color2 = ContextCompat.getColor(a_tprior.getContext(),yellow);
        int color3 = ContextCompat.getColor(a_tprior.getContext(),green);
        switch(task.t_prior){
            case "1": drawableId = R.drawable.ic_baseline_priority_high_24;
            a_tprior.setTextColor(color1);
            break;
            case "2": drawableId = R.drawable.ic_baseline_priority_middle_24;
            a_tprior.setTextColor(color2);
            break;
            case "3" : drawableId = R.drawable.ic_baseline_low_priority_24;
            a_tprior.setTextColor(color3);
            break;
            default: drawableId = R.drawable.ic_baseline_crop_square_24;
        }
        priorityIndicator.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(priorityIndicator.getContext(),drawableId));
    }

    public void bind2(Task task){
        final boolean[] checked = {true};
        checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
                    String pos = Integer.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()).toString();
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(checkbox.getContext()).edit().
                            putBoolean("checkbox" + pos , checked[0]).apply();
                    Toast.makeText(checkbox.getContext(), "Way to go! Now swipe to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else  {
                    checked[0] =false;
                    String pos = Integer.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()).toString();
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(checkbox.getContext()).edit().
                            putBoolean("checkbox" + pos, checked[0]).apply();
                }
            }
        }); String pos = Integer.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()).toString();
        boolean cb = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(checkbox.getContext()).getBoolean
                ("checkbox" + pos, false);
        checkbox.setChecked(cb);
    }

 }
public interface  OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Task ta);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

}

[image: Picture 1]   [image: Picture 2]

My code to delete in HomeFragment.java -

```
  new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull  RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull  RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setMessage("Do you want to delete this task?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Delete", ((dialog, which) ->
                            taskViewmodel.delete(adapter.getTaskAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()))))
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", ((dialog, which) -> adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)))
                    .setOnCancelListener(dialog -> adapter.notifyItemChanged(position))
                    .create().show();


        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Edit : I guess the problem is with the code associated with saving the state of the checkbox because the checkbox at a particular item position is checked so when the item is deleted, the below item takes its place and so it gets checked. Suppose item at 2nd position is checked, and I delete that item, then the item at the 3rd position takes its place and so that gets checked. I need to know how to resolve this.May i know what changes should i make to rectify this problem?
Thankyou

Comment: Do you notify change when an item is removed from the list?

Comment: I provide notifyItemChanged(position). I have posted my delete code now

Comment: Use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  after your notifyItemChanged(position).

Comment: @Danish It still doesn't work

Comment: the problem is you havent notified your adapter on your positive button.

Comment: Oh, so where should I add that code, because the setPositiveButton() can have only one argument

Comment: add the line in your onswiped after showing dialog box.More specifically after this:create().show()

Comment: @Danish Nope, it's still not working

Comment: @Harshitha you have to use adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position) and you are using lamba funfion in your setPositivebutton so you can add as many lines you want.

Comment: But it shows an error. I used it like this - setPositiveButton ("Delete"..... adapter.getTaskAt(...)), adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position). But it shows an error, the next few lines of code and this turns red

Comment: @Danish can you show how the code is

Comment: If its not confidential then you can upload your xml and your code,i will provide you with solution.

Comment: @Danish may I know which xml and code you're asking, the entire project? I just wanted to know how and where to add the code notifyItemRemoved(position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

back at the day, there was no delete intuition, now since you're storing the state of whether an item checked or not in SharedPreferences using its position, if you have 3 items where position =2  is checked, and you delete this checked item at pos=2, then the third item would take its place behaving as new item at pos=2, that's why when you delete one, all checked states will get shifted.

I guess there's no option here but to use some identifier in your Task class, where one Task is uniquely identified using this number/string and you use that unique identifier to store the items state in your SharedPreferences as a key.

a quick cheap way to do it is to make Task class behave like how Room database identify its automatic unique int/long identifiers.
the way to do it is by

- defining a static int/long counter field in your Task class that identifies how many ids you used so far so to not repeat any id that was taken before (even if it was deleted and not used now)
- define a private int/long id field in the Task class, while in the Task class constructor when you're initializing a new Task you would increment the static counter field and use this new value as a value for your private id for your newly created Task.
  N.B : you shouldn't increment the static value and assign a new id for every created task if the one you're creating an object for is an old one that you retrieved from SharedPreferences/Database that already have an old id, for that case you might have two constructors one that accepts an old id as paramter and one that increments the taskCounter and get a new id, you might also have two constructors that one calls the other incase you have some other paramteres you're passing to the task object at creation and you want to avoid duplicating code in both constructors.
- that way when you're checking status using SharedPreferences for some task, you would use the private id value of Task instead of its position.

your Task class might look like this (in case of two constructors without any additional code in the constructor):

```
public class Task {
    public static int tasksCounter =0;
    public int taskId ;
    ...
    //constructor for a new Task 
    public Task(){
        this.taskId= ++tasksCounter ;
    }
    //constructor for an old Task 
    public Task(int oldId){
        this.taskId= oldId ;
    }
```

your Task class might look like this (in case of two constructors and you want to avoid code dublication):

```
public class Task {
    public static int tasksCounter =0;
    public int taskId ;
    //you'd call that one if you're creating a completely new Task and it will call 
    the other constructor for you
    public Task(){
        Task(++tasksCounter)
    }
    //you'd call that one if you're creating a Task that you already have an id for
    public Task(int id){
        this.taskId= id ;
        //some other code here
    }
```

and in your adapter when you ask about whether its checked or not it would be like this :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(checkbox.getContext()).getBoolean
                ("checkbox" + task.taskId, false);
```

and when you the checkbox status get changed you'd change its value in preferences likewise using the `task.taskId` instead of position.

that of course would raise another problem that every time you start your application that static field will get reset to 0 again.
so you should store its value too in sharedpreferences maybe either

- when you create a new Task, its value will be incremented so you should store the new value
  or
- just before the activity or fragment getting destroyed by overriding the method `onDestroy()` in either the activity or the fragment, you should store the last value it had
  and when you start your activity or fragment you need to fetch it from sharedpreferences and assign it to `Task.tasksCounter`.

N.B : just incase you don't know, you get the value of static field by calling the class it self and you don't need to create a new object of this class to get its value, calling the next code is sufficent to get and edit its value :

```
Task.tasksCounter
```

and at the end,
since you have your complex data now (Task class), I would highly suggest to stop using SharedPreferences for storing everything and you start reading and switching to [Room Database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

[Room Database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) provides you with necessary storing abilities of a Database including :

- having an autoincrement identifier without having you worried about their values
- storing and getting your data with just one line of code with a simple query instead of calling get with keys a 100 times.

with changing your Task class into an entity that have an autoincrement field you'll be good to go and ready to use Room to store your tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much, I already had the task.id in my Task class, but didn't think of using it this way. This helped a ton!

Answer (score 1):

I am not much familiar with lambda function so I am sharing how I would have did the same task.I tried this code for my own app and it worked perfectly fine.
Check the below code:

```
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();//getAdapterPosition is depreciated, use getAbsoluteAdapterPosition
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete this task?");
          builder.setPositiveButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    taskViewmodel.delete(adapter.getTaskAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()))
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
              }
          });
                  builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          dialog.cancel();
                      }
                  });
                  builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                   adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                      }
                  }).show();

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: It's still not resolving my checkbox problem. I guess the problem is with the code associated with saving the state of the checkbox because the checkbox at a particular item position is checked so when the item is deleted, the below item takes its place and so it gets checked. Suppose item at 2nd position is checked, and I delete that item, then the item at the 3rd position takes its place and so that gets checked. I need to know how to resolve this, but thanks for your help though

Comment: yes that's the reason if you look at your checkbox code you are saving the state of your checkbox as checked in your shared preference and when you are deleting your recycler view item your checkbox is again set to checked.

Comment: Try making your checkbox public static then access it in your onSwipe and set to true. like this:checkbox.setChecked(false)

Comment: the onSwiped() is in HomeFragment.java and the checkbox is in TaskAdapter.java, they are in two different activities, how do I access it then?

Comment: Make it public static.

Comment: The checkbox is not being identified by Home fragment.java. It shows "cannot resolve symbol checkbox"

Comment: Placing public static Checkbox checkbox in your TaskAdapter class would resolve the issue of cannot resolve symbol checkbox.